# Older version of git sporadically finds bad RSA host keys in known_hosts

Tags: ssh, git, github

I'm using an older version of git (2.8) on an older box (RHEL6), and I’m noticing some odd behavior.

When the recent github RSA key exposure incident first happened and I did a `git pull`, I saw error messages like this:

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.113.3'
Offending key for IP in /home/gordonj/.ssh/known_hosts:10
Matching host key in /home/gordonj/.ssh/known_hosts:17
```

So I manually edited my known_hosts file and removed the offending line.  After repeating this process once or twice more, `git pull` finally succeeded and I thought that was the end of it.

But then the next day it happened again.  So I edited my known_hosts file again.

And then later it happened again.

And today it happened again.

Why is this happening?  Why does git suddenly find another bad key in my known_hosts file, when it (apparently) didn’t find that key earlier?

Comment: The error references an IP. Is the IP the same each time the error appears?

Comment: @muru I was able to find a few occurrences of the warning message in my terminal window history scrollback.  A couple of them do refer to the same IP, and there is one with a different IP.

Comment: Do you have HashKnownHosts turned on? (If the lines in known_hosts start `|1|base64|base64` and not a recognizable hostname or IPaddress, you do.) [**github.com has many IP addresses**](https://api.github.com/meta) and which one your system gets/uses varies; with hashing on, _each_ address you've connected to got its own line. Try deleting all lines with the bad _key_ (easiest way is to check the last 15-20 chars of the keyblob part, which are unique with overwhelming probability).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, my known_hosts entries start with `|1|base64|base64`.